# phpMyAdmin - Storing time in mm:ss:ms format

Tags: mysql, time, phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin I'm wanting to record a lap time for a race. The format needs to be in mm:ss:ms format.

How can I store this value in the database? Is there a data type that will allow it? I've tried time, timestamp and datetime but none of them store the value with milliseconds.

If this is not possible can I store it as an int or a varchar and then convert it in a select query to mm:ss:ms format for output display purposes?

Example Output:

```
1:35.547
```

So that's:

```
1 minute, 35 secs, 547 milliseconds
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> MySQL 5.6.4 and up expands fractional seconds support for `TIME`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP`values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision.

<sup>http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html</sup>

In earlier versions you have to implement the feature manually. The simplest option I can think of would be storing the milliseconds in a separate `SMALLINT` column, then:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    TIME_FORMAT(time_col, '%i minutes, %s seconds, '),
    milliseconds_col,
    ' milliseconds'
) FROM ...
```

Alternatively, you could store your times as `DECIMAL(10, 3)`. Unfortunately both approaches  require cumbersome, manual conversions.

Comment: That's not quite it but I think its as close as you can get without having to resort to just a plain old varchar. I know in SQL it's doable, it's just annoying how I have to work with phpMyAdmin...

Comment: You can use a display transformation to show the fractional time format as a format that's a bit easier to read. From the Structure tab of that table, click "Change" for your timestamp (etc) column, then select "Text/Plain: Dateformat" from the "Browser display transformation" dropdown.